# How can I find and click button element in cypress by the text on the button

Tags: button, cypress

I am having trouble finding a way of locating this element with cypress. I dont want to use the class name due to its complexity, and would like to use "Support" to keep my code clean.

```
<button type="button" class="border-secondary shadow-none btn btn-outline-primary">Support</button>
```

I have attempted cy.get('button').contains('Support').click() without success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's another variation of `.contains()` that will give you just the "Support" button

```js
cy.contains('button', 'Support')
```

Answer (score 0):

The only problem with using cy.contains, is that what if you want to verify the css color or text on it? cy.contains doesn't work most of the time.
I personally would still use the class but add a wildcard "*"
ex:
`cy.get('button[class*="btn-outline-primary"]')` <-- next what you want to do is check it on the webpage, so go to the webpage you are testing and: rightClick/Inspect, then use ctl f, then copy and paste: `button[class*="btn-outline-primary"]` in the find section <-- this way you'll know that you can find it and Cypress does see it.
If it does work then:

```
cy.get('button[class*="btn-outline-primary"]').should(verifyText =>
{
     expect(verifyText).have.text('Support').have.css('background-color', 'rgb(0, 0, 0)')
```

})

Try using cy.contains() when you just want to only minor stuff like clicking. But if you need to assert, try defining it more with cy.get(). Hope it helps.